# function undefined when setting function with .attr()

Tags: jquery

I get handler not defined onpaste when:

```
<div class="inp email" contenteditable="plaintext-only"/></div>
<div class="inp passw" contenteditable="plaintext-only"/></div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        function handler(_this,e){
            alert('paste');
            }
        $('.inp').each(i,v){
            $(this).attr({'onpaste':'handler(this,e)'});
            });
    });
</script>
```

Why when I am declairing the function before even adding it to the div?

EDIT: im using jquery 1.8.3 I don't want to see alternative methods I am more concerned with **why do i get undefined**, the paste event is not important, please don't miss the point of my question (in bold)

Comment: Your `handler` function only exists in your `ready` handler's scope. That said, why do you want to create attributes in order to handle events? Go the unobtrusive way and use `on()` instead.

Comment: Using jQuery you should never add event handlers with attr. Never. Not once. *Jamais*.

Comment: Re: your edit, your answer is in the first sentence of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the function in the local scope of the `ready` event handler, but when the event happens the code runs in the global scope, and the function is not visible there.

If you declare the function in the global scope, it can be found:

```
function handler(_this,e){
  alert('paste');
}

$(function(){
  $('.inp').each(i,v){
    $(this).attr({'onpaste':'handler(this,e)'});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not do it the proper way to begin with

```
$(function(){
    $('.inp').on('paste', function(e) {
        alert('paste');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.on()` with paste event rather than adding event as an attrbute like this:

```
$('.inp').on('paste',function(e){
    alert('paste');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three problems there:

1. The scope. The handler is in the ready event handler scope which you need to take out to global scope. This has been answered by others as well.
2. You can't pass the `e` here.
3. The syntax of `.each` is `.each(function (index, element)...`

So in order for it to actually work (for whatever bizarre reason), your code should be:

```
function handler(_this) {
    alert('paste');
}

$(function () {
    $('.inp').each(function (i, v) {
        $(this).attr({
            'onpaste': 'handler(this)'
        });
    });
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/AFZN4/1/**